# How to create multiple regex conditions with Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, doctrine-orm

When using Doctrine ORM with Postgres, how to create the same as this SQL does with QueryBuilder:

```
WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL AND (column1 ~= :pattern OR column1 ~= :pattern2)
```

I'd also like avoiding having all conditions in one line like following:

```
->andWhere('column2 IS NOT NULL AND (column1 ~= :pattern OR column1 ~= :pattern2'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to

1) create custom DQL function

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Node;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use function sprintf;

/**
 * "REGEX" "(" StringPrimary "," StringPrimary ")"
 */
final class RegexFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    /** @var Node */
    public $fieldExpression;

    /** @var Node */
    public $patternExpression;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker) : string
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%s :: TEXT ~* %s',
            $this->fieldExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker),
            $this->patternExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker)
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser) : void
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->fieldExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->patternExpression = $parser->StringPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

2) register it in [config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)

3) then in can be used in query builder or expression builder like this:

```
$expr->orX()->add('REGEX(e.field, :pattern) = true');
```

Answer (score 0):

[`martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine` @ GitHub](https://github.com/martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine/) adds support for `REGEXP`, `SIMILAR_TO`, `JSON_GET_FIELD` and `CONTAINS` operators, among others.

`SIMILAR_TO` is PostreSQL operator for pattern matching with regular expressions (see [9.7.2. SIMILAR TO Regular Expressions @ PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP)).

For using regular expressions with MariaDB database, [`beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` @ GitHub](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) seems to be the response.