# ApiPlatform Regex property filter with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm trying to add a custom filter to an entity in my ApiPlatform project that allows me to filter on specific property given a regex pattern.

Following the ApiPlatform documentation I came up with the following class (this is a near copy of the their example, only the where-clause is different):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractContextAwareFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

final class RegexFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter
{
    protected function filterProperty(
        string $property,
        $value,
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        string $operationName = null
    ) {
        // otherwise filter is applied to order and page as well
        if (
            !$this->isPropertyEnabled($property, $resourceClass) ||
            !$this->isPropertyMapped($property, $resourceClass)
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $parameterName = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName($property); // Generate a unique parameter name to avoid collisions with other filters
        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere(sprintf('(o.%s ~ :%s) = true', $property, $parameterName))
            ->setParameter($parameterName, $value);
    }

    // This function is only used to hook in documentation generators (supported by Swagger and Hydra)
    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        if (!$this->properties) {
            return [];
        }

        $description = [];
        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description["regexp_$property"] = [
                'property' => $property,
                'type' => 'string',
                'required' => false,
                'swagger' => [
                    'description' => 'Filter using a regex. This will appear in the Swagger documentation!',
                    'name' => 'Custom name to use in the Swagger documentation',
                    'type' => 'Will appear below the name in the Swagger documentation',
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```

When I run my code this results in the following DQL:

```
SELECT o FROM App\Entity\Vehicle o WHERE (o.licensePlate ~ :licensePlate_p1) = true ORDER BY o.id ASC
```

However I cannot get the Lexer to understand the tilde ~ character:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 56: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '~'
```

How can I make Doctrine understand the tilde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was pretty close, [simPod's answer helped me fill the gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50675893/3514278).

- I copied his custom DQL function and added it in my Doctrine yaml configuration
- In my `RegexFilter` I had to slightly modify the where-clause:

  ```
  ->andWhere(sprintf('REGEX(o.%s, :%s) = true', $property, $parameterName))
  ```